# offset anchor link from top of page

Tags: jquery, offset, scrollto

Currently I have a script that opens a div from another page, however when you land on the target page the heading above the div is not visible as it is hidden behind a fixed header when the anchor ID is selected form the home page. I want to offset the heading before the target div so it is visible below the site header.

HTML...

```
<h2 class="section-heading toggle">content 1 heading</h2>
<div id="content1" class="slide-content">content</div>
```

jQuery...

```
var hash = window.location.hash; // 
if(hash != "") {
    var id = hash.substr(1); // get rid of #
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block'; 
    $(hash).prev().first().addClass("open");
}
```

Comment: Can you add screenshots as well as it's not quite clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: i cant i'm afraid, i'll try and be more specific...